# SwiftUI ForEach not correctly updating in scrollview

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI ScrollView with an HStack and a ForEach inside of it. The ForEach is built off of a Published variable from an ObservableObject so that as items are added/removed/set it will automatically update in the view. However, I'm running into multiple problems:

1. If the array starts out empty and items are then added it will not show them.
2. If the array has some items in it I can add one item and it will show that, but adding more will not.

If I just have an HStack with a ForEach neither of the above problems occur. As soon as it's in a ScrollView I run into the problems.

Below is code that can be pasted into the Xcode SwiftUI Playground to demonstrate the problem. At the bottom you can uncomment/comment different lines to see the two different problems.

If you uncomment problem 1 and then click either of the buttons you'll see just the HStack updating, but not the HStack in the ScrollView *even though* you see init print statements for those items.

If you uncomment problem 2 and then click either of the buttons you should see that after a second click the the ScrollView updates, but if you keep on clicking it will not update - even though just the HStack will keep updating and init print statements are output for the ScrollView items.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine

final class Testing: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [String] = []

    init() {}

    init(items: [String]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct SVItem: View {
    var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        print("init SVItem: \(value)")
        self.value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
    }
}

struct HSItem: View {
    var value: String

    init(value: String) {
        print("init HSItem: \(value)")
        self.value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
    }
}

public struct PlaygroundRootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var testing: Testing

    public init() {}

    public var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("ScrollView")
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack() {
                    ForEach(self.testing.items, id: \.self) { value in
                        SVItem(value: value)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            Spacer()
            Text("HStack")
            HStack {
                ForEach(self.testing.items, id: \.self) { value in
                    HSItem(value: value)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 30)
            .background(Color.red)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("APPEND button")
                self.testing.items.append("A")
            }, label: { Text("APPEND ITEM") })
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("SET button")
                self.testing.items = ["A", "B", "C"]
            }, label: { Text("SET ITEMS") })
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(
    // problem 1
    rootView: PlaygroundRootView().environmentObject(Testing())

    // problem 2
    // rootView: PlaygroundRootView().environmentObject(Testing(items: ["1", "2", "3"]))
)
```

Is this a bug? Am I missing something? I'm new to iOS development..I did try wrapping the actual items setting/appending in the DispatchQueue.main.async, but that didn't do anything.

Also, maybe unrelated, but if you click the buttons enough the app seems to crash.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into the same issue. Solved with empty array check & invisible HStack

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { _ in
        RowItem()
    }

    if (self.items.count == 0) {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: I too do prefer this hack to the one with the fake initial value inside the array. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

It is known behaviour of `ScrollView` with observed empty containers - it needs something (initial content) to calculate initial size, so the following solves your code behaviour

```
@Published var items: [String] = [""]
```

In general, in such scenarios I prefer to store in array some "easy-detectable initial value", which is removed when first "real model value" appeared and added again, when last disappears. Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I tried that in the code above and still had the same problem as problem 2.

Comment: Hmm, I've got 11.3 and while it will shows the first item added/replaced after a second button tap, it won't do anything after that.

Comment: I observed several major complains against Xcode 11.3 here on SO, so might be it worth downgrade... I'd even say to 11.1, because 11.2 also have several bad issues with List & NavigationView.

Comment: Downgraded to 11.1 and it works. Still has some quirks, but it shows up!

Answer (score 2):

For better readability and also because the answer didn't work for me. I'd suggest @TheLegend27 answer to be slightly modified like this:

```
if self.items.count != 0 {

   ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
       ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { _ in
           RowItem()
       }
   }

}
```