# SwiftUI View doesn't show data until I switch to light or dark mode

Tags: ios, swiftui

This one has me really stumped. I'm loading a ScrollView/VStack with data from an ObservedViewModel as the user types into the search field. Note, this works perfectly in an iOS 14 device but this is the behavior I'm getting on 13.5

The data loads and the view gets refreshed (all breakpoints are being hit) but I can't really see it until I switch the device from dark mode to light mode or vice versa.
Any ideas?

[image]

My Search View:

```
struct EventsSearchView: View {
    var searchText: String
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var eventsViewModel: EventsBySearchViewModel = EventsBySearchViewModel(service: EventsBySearchService())
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationProvider
    
    @State var lat: String = ""
    @State var long: String = ""
    
    init(searchText: String) {
        self.searchText = searchText
        
        locationManager = LocationProvider()
        do {
            try locationManager.start()
        } catch {
            print("no location access")
            locationManager.requestAuthorization()
        }
        UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            eventsViewModel.getEventsBySearch(keyword: searchText, latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(eventsViewModel.events, id: \.self) { event in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            CardView(event: event, lat: lat, long: long)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.themeBackground)
                .onAppear {
                    if self.eventsViewModel.events.count == 0 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            
                            if locationManager.authorizationStatus != nil {
                                self.lat = String(locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0)
                                self.long = String(locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)
                            }
                            
                            locationManager.stop()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.themeBackground)
    }
}

    struct EventsSearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            EventsSearchView(searchText: "")
        }
    }
```

And this is the view that creates it

```
struct TopView: View {
    @State var tabSelected: Int = 0
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var index = 0
    @State private var showEventsSearchView: Bool = false
    @State private var searchKeyword: String = ""
    
    let spacing: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            SearchView(showSearch: $showEventsSearchView, searchText: $searchKeyword)
            
            if showEventsSearchView {
                EventsSearchView(searchText: searchKeyword)
            } else {
```

Comment: It is obvious that view is not refreshed on search... would you show your code?

Comment: I can put break points in all stages of the code (service, view model, view) and they all get hit as if it does. Updaing my post withe some code...

Comment: Again, it works fine on iOS 14

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with a simple view with a ScrollView/VStack loading data from a viewmodel object. Same behavior. I changed the ScrollView/VStack to a List and it started working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is related to this issue. The empty HStack HACK worked
[scrollview issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316078/swiftui-foreach-not-correctly-updating-in-scrollview)